# String from struct pointer

Tags: json, go

As a student of Go I encountered this problem.

My ultimate goal of doing this is to convert `*blockchain` into a valid JSON string.

My structs are:

```
type Blockchain struct{
    blocks []Block `json:"blocks"`
    difficulty int `json:"difficulty"`
}

type Block struct{
    index int `json:"index"`
    timestamp string `json:"timestamp"`
    data string `json:"data"`
    previousHash string `json:"previousHash"`
    hash string `json:"hash"`
    nonce int `json:"nonce"`
}
```

I have the following code:

```
var s = fmt.Sprintf("%#v", *blockchain)
print(s)
```

Which gives me the following:

> main.Blockchain{blocks:[]main.Block{main.Block{index:1, timestamp:"2019-04-06 12:50:54", data:"Genesis block", previousHash:"", hash:"eca16d7bdd20a91f471fc3231fa5de7d892fb540789673d64f29a7b93719b74b", nonce:0}, main.Block{index:2, timestamp:"2019-04-06 12:50:54", data:"d.duck", previousHash:"eca16d7bdd20a91f471fc3231fa5de7d892fb540789673d64f29a7b93719b74b", hash:"2096ccfa6fdd8305f0e31c2e6858173a21764be4c8e1d3d50c9c31193bf06a2a", nonce:0}, main.Block{index:3, timestamp:"2019-04-06 12:50:54", data:"dumbo", previousHash:"2096ccfa6fdd8305f0e31c2e6858173a21764be4c8e1d3d50c9c31193bf06a2a", hash:"d76d4a002c6dde01009e3122aa1ccfb455e1d453ac83e2a0eb123c6080943cdb", nonce:0}}, difficulty:4}

Obviously invalid JSON.

Any suggestions?

I also tried the following:

```
var json, err = json.Marshal(*blockchain)

if err != nil{
    panic(err.Error())
}
var s = fmt.Sprintf("%#v", json)

print(s)
```

It gave me the following:

```
[]byte{0x7b, 0x7d}
```

Answer (score 1):

The fields on structs need to be exported (start with capital letter). This is required because JSON marshalling uses reflection, and that requires the field to be exported (to be visible).

Also `json.Marshal` first return value is the JSON.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Blockchain struct {
    Blocks     []Block `json:"blocks"`
    Difficulty int     `json:"difficulty"`
}

type Block struct {
    Index        int    `json:"index"`
    Timestamp    string `json:"timestamp"`
    Data         string `json:"data"`
    PreviousHash string `json:"previousHash"`
    Hash         string `json:"hash"`
    Nonce        int    `json:"nonce"`
}

func main() {
    bc := &Blockchain{
        Blocks: []Block{
            Block{},
        },
        Difficulty: 1,
    }
    v, err := json.Marshal(bc)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(v))
}
```

This prints:

```
{"blocks":[{"index":0,"timestamp":"","data":"","previousHash":"","hash":"","nonce":0}],"difficulty":1}
```

Comment: I tried this:
```
 v, err := json.Marshal(&blockchain)
 if err != nil {
  panic(err.Error)
 }
 fmt.Println(string(v))
```
Got this:
```
runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 1000000000-byte limit
fatal error: stack overflow

```

Comment: @pigfox The code in the answer [runs without error](https://play.golang.org/p/v87C7fJC6MJ).  Do the types in the question have any methods?

Comment: No, they do not not.
The difference between the answer which uses a hard coded struct and my issue is that I have a pointer to a struct as you can see in my example above.
json.Marshal(*blockchain)

Comment: @pigfox One of the types **does** have a method based on your comments in another question.  That method that is the cause of the problem.  In the future, please post a [mcve].